# insert comma after every letter but skipping quotes

Tags: python, string

I want to split a string using commas, but retaining the grouping in quotes (either single or double).

Examples (Input -> Desired Output):

```
"ABC" -> "A,B,C"
"AB'CD'E" -> "A,B,'CD',E"
'AB"CDG"EF' -> 'A,B,"CDG",E,F'
```

I was thinking iterate over the string and skip when encounters quotes, but not sure how to handle finding index of the closing quote.

```
def convert(str):
    new_str = ''
    for c in str:
        if c not in ["'", '"']:
            new_str = new_str + c + ','
        else:
            ??
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this just need to handle single quotes?

Comment: @Nathan either single or double, I will add more explainable to my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are easier ways to do in 2 lines of code but I wanted to complete the logic in your function. You need to test where the quotes starts and where it ends because in that interval there is no actions to be done

```
def convert(str):
    new_str =str[0]
    quote=False
    for c in str[1:]:
        if c in ["'", '"']:
            if quote==False:
                new_str=new_str+','
            quote=not quote
        if c not in ["'", '"'] and quote==False:
            new_str = new_str + ','+c
        else:
            new_str = new_str + c 
    return new_str
```

Comment: Thank you Majd!  I couldn’t wrapped my head around how to track the quote position and this helps a lot!

Comment: you are welcome, glad that this helped you. would be great to mark my answer as accepted. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd try using a regular expression for this; don't write out a parser yourself if you don't really need to.

I'm assuming that your string consists only of alphabetical characters, that all quoted groups are non-empty (i.e. there are always some characters between the quotes), and that you don't have any unclosed quotes.

This seems to work:

```py
import re

s = "AB'CD'E"
splits = re.findall("\"[A-z]+\"|'[A-z]+'|[A-z]", s)
# ['A', 'B', "'CD'", 'E']
",".join(splits)
# "A,B,'CD',E"
```

The regular expression given looks for groups of alphabetic characters enclosed by double-quotes or by single-quotes or just for single characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace quoted substrings and unquoted chars with `re.sub` assuming your strings are well-formed and the quotes are balanced:

```
re.sub("('[^']*'|.)(?!$)", r'\1,',  "AB'CD'E")
# A,B,'CD',E
```

If you need something more complicated, perhaps try parsing character by character as you suggested. Keep track of the current state - whether the current character is in a quoted sequence or not - with a variable.